# c Function is not called

Tags: c, string-comparison, c-strings, function-call, function-definition

my written C function is not called, although I pass the two char to the function. I do not get the return value I would expect from the while loop. Anyone have an idea what the problem is?

```
int string_compare(char v[], char w[]);

int main (void) {
  char v[] = "N";
  char w[] = "M";
  int string_compare(char v[], char w[]);
  return 0;
}

int string_compare(char v[], char w[])
{
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (v[i] != w[i]) {
      return v[i] - w[i];
    }
    if (v[i] == '\0' || w[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Max

Comment: You don't call it but redundantly declare it inside `main()`.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, `int string_compare(char v[], char w[]);` is a function declaration, not a function call. A function call would look like `int result = string_compare(v, w);`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot wrong here. To call the function `string_compare` you need to pass two character arrays to it. You then need to assign the return value to a variable.

So

```
int string_compare(char v[], char w[]);

int main (void) {
  char v[] = "N";
  char w[] = "M";
  int x = string_compare(v, w);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}

int string_compare(char v[], char w[])
{
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (v[i] != w[i]) {
      return v[i] - w[i];
    }
    if (v[i] == '\0' || w[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
int string_compare( const char s1[], const char s2[] );
```

That is the parameters should have the qualifier `const` because the function shall not change passed to it strings.

The condition in this if statement

```
if (v[i] == '\0' || w[i] == '\0') {
```

can be simplified like

```
if ( v[i] == '\0' ) {
```

because when the control achieves this point `v[i]` and `w[i]` are equal each other. So it is enough to check only one character whether it is equal to zero.

The variable `i` used as an index

```
int i = 0;
```

shall have the type `size_t` because an object of the type `int` in general is unable to store all values of the type `size_t` (of string lengths) that is the return type of the function `strlen` or of the operator `sizeof`.

```
size_t i = 0;
```

However introducing this auxiliary variable is redundant.

In any case the definition of the function is too complicated.

At last this record in the function `main`

```
int string_compare(char v[], char w[]);
```

is a redundant function declaration. The function `main` does not call the function `string_compare`. It only declares it one more in its block scope.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be declared, defined and called.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int string_compare( const char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1; ++s2;
    }
    
    return *s1 - *s2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "N";
    char *s2 = "M";
  
    printf( "string_compare( \"%s\", \"%s\" ) = %d\n", s1, s2,
                             string_compare( s1, s2 ) );
  
    printf( "string_compare( \"%s\", \"%s\" ) = %d\n", s2, s1,
                             string_compare( s2, s1 ) );
                           
    s2 = s1;
    
    printf( "string_compare( \"%s\", \"%s\" ) = %d\n", s1, s2,
                             string_compare( s1, s2 ) );
  
                           
  
  return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
string_compare( "N", "M" ) = 1
string_compare( "M", "N" ) = -1
string_compare( "N", "N" ) = 0
```